# Problems with writing passwords in CMD

Tags: cmd, passwords

If someone types a password with one or more spaces it will quit and return:
Unexpected (...)

For example:

I enter the password: test 1

It returns: unexpected 1

And my the batch just closes!
Any ideas how make it ignore spaces?

Here's the full code:

```
@echo off
if time GTR 14.00 goto ALLOW

title Security

echo Your computer started at %date%! Time: %time%! >> Reports.txt

echo taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe
shutdown /s /t 60
msg * Please enter the password in the box!

:START
cls
set /p PSW = Enter the password here: 

if %PSW% == test (
goto END
) else (
if not %PSW% == test goto TRYAGAIN
)

goto start

:END

shutdown /a
msg * Correct!
start explorer.exe
taskkill /f /IM cmd.exe

:TRYAGAIN
msg * Wrong! Try again!
goto START 

:ALLOW
taskkill /f /IM cmd.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes protect spaces and `&` characters etc.

```
if "%PSW%" == "test" (
goto END
) else (
goto TRYAGAIN
)
```